# Post data Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, post, google-chrome-extension, http-post, postdata

!!Question edited

Sorry for my english. I hope you can help me. Thank you

I'm making a google chrome extension .
the purpose of the application:

Clicking on the Chrome extension will take the price of the product on the current site. Then it will post this price to a site prepared with php.

**Code:**

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "get current html of page ",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "my first extension",

  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
   
  "host_permissions":[

        "https://*/",
        "http://*/",
        "https://yaziciemre.com/",
        "http://localhost/*/",
        "http://www.google.com/*"
    ],

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

background.js

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    files: ["parse_page.js"],
  });

  const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    const baseurl="https://yaziciemre.com/ip.php";
    xhr.open("POST",baseurl,true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    let data=ps1;
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
          }
        }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ "price": data }));

});
```

parse_page.js

```js
var ps1 = document.getElementsByClassName('s1wl91l5-4 cBVHJG')[0].innerHTML;  
window.alert(ps1);
```

I store the price of the product on the current site in a variable but I can't post this price to a site created with php
The url of the site I want to post the price of:
https://yaziciemre.com/ip.php

When I click on the chrome extension, I can get the price and
keep it in a variable.
how can i post this price?

please click the picture

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3EgH.png
```

Comment: There's no universal solution. Each site has its own selector.

Comment: thank you bro. I have another question. 
I want to send these codes to python with ajax, how can I do it? @wOxxOm